# PDFbox 2.0.20 - new PagePane() throws RuntineException

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

since i've updated my PDFbox to latest (2.0.8->2.0.20) i get a runtime error while instantiating a PagePane class.

I tried to change JDK versions, also get latest dependencies from maven, switched my project to maven to get rid of dependencies.

Anyway i get an error while executing this raw snippet (running in main void) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    File file = new File("/home/bujakowski/Pobrane/test.pdf");
    PDDocument doc;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(file);

        JLabel lab = new JLabel();
        PagePane pp = new PagePane(doc, doc.getPage(0).getCOSObject(),new JLabel());
        f.add(pp.getPanel());
        f.setVisible(true);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

I also tried with different PDF versions - scanned image, textual only, mixed content, old PDF versions and latest ones.

I also've seen the error can come from BufferedImage called in PagePane jar.
I use JDK 11 as default.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane$RenderWorker.done(PagePane.java:434)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:750)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:847)
> at
> java.desktop/sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:857)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:317)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:249)   at
> java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:613)   at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane$RenderWorker.done(PagePane.java:414)
> ... 19 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.ui.RotationMenu.getRotationDegrees(RotationMenu.java:102)
> at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane$RenderWorker.doInBackground(PagePane.java:391)
> at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane$RenderWorker.doInBackground(PagePane.java:384)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Exception in
> thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane.ancestorAdded(PagePane.java:271)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.fireAncestorAdded(AncestorNotifier.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.componentShown(AncestorNotifier.java:193)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6463)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6411)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2049)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5007)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4839)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at
> org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.pagepane.PagePane.ancestorRemoved(PagePane.java:283)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.fireAncestorRemoved(AncestorNotifier.java:108)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AncestorNotifier.componentHidden(AncestorNotifier.java:208)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentHidden(AWTEventMulticaster.java:197)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentHidden(AWTEventMulticaster.java:197)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6466)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6411)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2049)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5007)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4839)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: PagePane isn't an API. This is a part of PDFDebugger, a closed application that is changed from time to time. In the part that goes NPE, RotationMenu.getRotationDegrees() is called, and that one calls its own instance. You need to initialize this calling "RotationMenu.getInstance()". However I expect more troubles.

Comment: Ok, but it actually worked before. 
Do You suggest i have to workaround my own PagePane component?

Comment: Another one is "allowSubsampling", that one needs to be intialiazed too ("allowSubsampling = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(ALLOW_SUBSAMPLING);")

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you either try to modify PDFDebugger as it is, or look closely in the source code of PDFDebugger to see the dependencies. Lots of stuff has been added since 2.0.8.

Comment: This probably won’t fix the problem, but as general advice it is better to just add a `throws IOException` to the main method signature than to just swallow the catch. Also it is safer to close the pdf, for example with `try (doc = ...) { ... }